Generate a stacked bar chart in python out of groupby based on multi-index
I would like to generate a stacked bar chart (ideally in seaborn), but happy to go with the native pandas plotting functionality. Let me introduce some test data to make things clear.
In [353]: import pandas as pd

In [354]: import seaborn as sns

In [355]: df = pd.DataFrame({"Cat":["A", "B","A","B","A","B","A","B","C"], "Time":[0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1], "ID":[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1]})

In [356]: df
Out[356]: 
  Cat  Time  ID
0   A     0   0
1   B     0   0
2   A     1   0
3   B     1   0
4   A     0   1
5   B     0   1
6   A     1   1
7   B     1   1
8   C     1   1

In [357]: df.groupby(["ID","Cat"]).count()
Out[357]: 
        Time
ID Cat      
0  A       2
   B       2
1  A       2
   B       2
   C       1

In [358]: 

What I would like to see here, is on the x-axis the ID's where on the y axis I get the count (column Time) stacked by the variable Cat, e.g. for ID 1, I want to see a stacked coloured bar where the sizes are 2, 2 and 1. I've tried the following without succeeding:
df.groupby(["ID","Cat"]).count().plot(kind="bar", stacked=True, x="ID")

as it seems it can't handle the multi-axis. Any help much appreciated!
EDIT
This EDIT is to add the trouble I'm having with the legenbox being placed outside of the plotting window. The real code I'm using
p = so.Plot(df.astype({"Time": "category"}),x='Time', color='Category').add(so.Bar(), so.Count(), so.Stack())
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2560/120, 1335/120))
today = dt.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")
plt.grid()
p.on(ax).save(f"{today}_barchart_sources_{c}.png")
plt.close()



You would need to unstack the Cat (also only aggregate Time):
(df.groupby(['ID', 'Cat'])['Time'].count().unstack('Cat')
   .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
)

Output:

Alternatively, with seaborn's object interface, for which you don't need to pre-aggregate the data. See Stack for more examples:
import seaborn.objects as so

(so.Plot(df.astype({'ID': 'category'}), x='ID', color='Cat')
   .add(so.Bar(), so.Count(), so.Stack())
)

NB. converting ID to category to avoid having a numeric x-axis.
Output:


That is fantastic. Do you know why in my case, specifying the subplots figsize leads to the legend box being cut off? I've added the real code snippet and figure in my question. Happy to accept afterwards. Many thanks for your help!

@swissy Not sure, I cannot reproduce your issue, maybe try to add .layout(engine='tight') to your so.Plot()... command.
